# SMIME can't be validated by receiver when using newer version of Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, smime

I am using BC to encrypt and sign an SMIME message for use with AS2.  The code we have works fine with an absolutely ancient version of bouncy castle, `bcmail-1.4:125`.  Upgrading to anything newer causes the receiver of the message (not too ancient Cyclone server) to fail to verify the message. (e.g. the *earliest v in maven* causes this too.  These are the versions without API changes (e.g. 1.38).

Since we use JDK 1.7 (and 1.8), I've been trying to update this to a newer version of BC, java-mail, etc.  I've upgraded all of bouncy castle to `bcmail-jdk15on:1.51` and `bcprov-jdk15on:1.51`, along with java mail, and followed the examples in the `bcmail` package.  However, I am still getting an error from Cyclone saying `integrity-check-failed`.

I am fairly certain the error is with how I am doing signing. When I disable signing and only use encryption it processes correctly.  Also, I can correctly receive a signed response from the remote server and verify the signature, which is how I get the error message out (from content-disposition on the MimeMultiPart).

- The certificates are created by openssl/self signed/etc, stored in pkcs12 file
- Unlimited strength policies are in place
- `senderKey` is a `BCRSAPrivateCrtKey`
- `senderCert`

  - `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.x509.X509CertificateObject`

**Failing**: The current code is this, using `bcmail-jdk15on:1.51` & etc

```
SMIMESignedGenerator gen = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder()
           .setProvider("BC")
           .build("SHA1withRSA", senderKey, senderCert));
// gen.addCertificates(new JcaCertStore(list(senderCert))); old v. doesn't add certs
MimeMultipart smime = gen.generate(part); // MimeBodyPart passed in to function
MimeBodyPart tmpBody = new MimeBodyPart();
tmpBody.setContent(signedData);
tmpBody.setHeader("Content-Type", signedData.getContentType()
```

**Previously working code** looks like this and uses `bcmail-1.4:1.25`.  Upgrading to 1.3x also causes a failure on the other end when decrypting (irrespective of which jdk I run on, 1.6 - 1.8)

```
MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
body.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes[], contentType, null);));
SMIMESignedGenerator sGen = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
// SHA1 resolves to "1.3.14.3.2.26", FWIW
sGen.addSigner(senderKey, senderCert, getBouncyCastleAlgorithmId("SHA1"));
MimeMultipart signedData = sGen.generate(part, "BC");
// this is then encrypted & streamed, no issues there
```

**Common Setup Code**

```
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(data, "application/EDIFACT", null);
part.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
part.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
part.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/EDIFACT");
```

I have a feeling it has something to do with how I am adding (or manipulating) the `senderCert`, which is the local application's X509.

**Update**

I've made the new code more in-line with what the old produces by removing the certificate:

- It no longer includes the cert in the signed message.  old version didn't
- The entire mime multi-part content is now *exactly* the same length (1095 bytes) as before
- The format (headers, etc) is now exactly the same
- The signed part is now nearly identical.  There is a portion that seems to vary based on the time (???), though, and that changes each time.  I can't get openssl to verify this message yet, no idea why.

Here is sample output, FWIW.  The text in `[]` is the only part that changes.

```
------=_Part_1_1448572667.1409621469842
Content-Type: application/EDIFACT
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

this is a test

------=_Part_1_1448572667.1409621469842
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature; name=smime.p7s; smime-type=signed-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7s"
Content-Description: S/MIME Cryptographic Signature

MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAMYIBpDCCAaAC
AQEwgZ4wgZAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAmNuMREwDwYDVQQIDAhzaGFuZ2hhaTESMBAGA1UEBwwJY2hhbmdu
aW5nMREwDwYDVQQKDAhwb3dlcmUyZTEOMAwGA1UECwwFaXRkZXYxEjAQBgNVBAMMCWFiLWNsaWVu
dDEjMCEGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYUYWItY2xpZW50QG15Q29ycC5jb20CCQClDAGwq37A/jAJBgUrDgMC
GgUAoF0wGAYJKoZIhvcNAQkDMQsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAcBgkqhkiG9w0BCQUxDxcNMTQwOTAyMDEz
M[TA5]WjAjBgkqhkiG9w0BCQQxFgQUG6KkoqPBvE7Kd9dB0eop/aUTya0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAE
gYB[h9N4maow9aoTQ8QBGgXEYE+xgXSmRPy+ufIsMpuS0Yys/1t3AfXSSI7WKgLMRKYXve8gdb4Gn
dqecHzkBwBq4hebt9YK+E30E6DpZpCwErsgDVaU/ExBA5gauPWneysy+s2bE5Y6pNZ7Qf3kGU5kI
UjlOF/LUNkCsgT5z//]5N6QAAAAAAAA==
------=_Part_1_1448572667.1409621469842--
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of debugging and dumping of files and so on, I proved that it had soemething to do with the digest calculation.  In a specific location in the signed body part is the content MIC (base64 of the digest).  Somehow this value did not match what the other side did...

Once I had that, and some more time with google, I finally turned up [more information on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/openas2/discussion/265567/thread/0c12bb53) confirming this.  Helpful since it mentions my specific version of BC.  To quote:

> The problem is that BC >= 1.27 will "canonicalize" all messages that
>   are not sent with content-transfer-encoding binary.
>
> What does this mean?
>
> In the S/MIME rfc it says that all messages should be converted to a
>   "canonical" form before computing the MIC.  The "canonical" form for
>   text messages is that EOL is indicated by CR, LF.  The rfc's are
>   silent on what the canonical form for other content types is.  Many
>   S/MIME implementations (e.g. openssl, Bouncy Castle after 1.27)
>   incorrectly assume that the canonical form for all messages except
>   those sent with content-transfer-encoding binary is that every LF
>   should be preceeded by a CR.
>
> So if a BC 1.25 used sends a message including bare LF characters then
>   the MIC validation will fail if the message is received by an
>   application using BC >= 1.27, or openssl smime, or many other S/MIME
>   implementations.
>
> OpenAS2 should be fixed to use content-transfer-encoding binary.

**This only appears to work if you set the encoding on the *MIME Body Part***  I had verified the same results (that failed on the server) by doing the JCA route manually, the lightweight route, and also the CMS route.

With that information I made a simple change to the sender....

```
MimeBodyPart part = //.. make mime body part from file
part.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
```

The funny part about this is that changing anything to do with the `SMIMESignedGenerator()` seems to have no effect:

```
gen = SMIMESignedGenerator("binary");  // nothing, even though the docs say to set this
```

My final signing function looks like this, for anyone interested:

```
SMIMESignedGenerator gen = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
SignerInfoGenerator sigGen = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder()
        .setProvider(BC)
        .build("SHA1withRSA", senderKey, senderCert);
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(sigGen);
MimeMultipart smime = gen.generate(part);
MimeBodyPart tmpBody = new MimeBodyPart();
tmpBody.setContent(smime);
tmpBody.setHeader("Content-Type", smime.getContentType());
return tmpBody;
```

The original file is just one line:

```
this is a test
```

The input that gets signed is this:

```
Content-Type: application/EDIFACT
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

this is a test
```

Debugging info:

```
data bytes:
436F6E74656E742D547970653A206170706C69636174696F6E2F454449464143540D0
A436F6E74656E742D5472616E736665722D456E636F64696E673A2062696E6172790D
0A0D0A74686973206973206120746573740A

digest mic: {
   "algorithmId":   "1.3.14.3.2.26"
   "digest bytes":  "CEC2C6614A481DFDF45C801FD6F2A51BC53D3FDF"
   "digest base64": "zsLGYUpIHf30XIAf1vKlG8U9P98="
}
```

Not this does not attach the signature, or add any capabilities, and uses a v1 x509 cert.  I may change that stuff now that this is all working again.

I really do wish all this was more transparent... BC internally is indirection upon indirection, though I understand why.  It's still better internally than the old version. I can't say that I haven't found a lot of examples, but the BC test cases don't seem the best (e.g. I couldn't find one that verified against an *expected* digest value after SMIME'ing. maybe I missed it)

Comment: I struggled on this for over a week then your answer pointed me in the right direction: my email template had a text body part formatted using LF only, and that was causing the signature validation to fail on Outlook whereas a simpler test case (a single line of text) I built the code upon was working perfectly

Comment: Awesome, so happy this helped you.  This was a nightmare to debug, and I can imagine how much worse it must have been with with _outlook_ ! :D

Comment: In Thunderbird every signature was invalid, I have to change the algorithm to SHA1withRSA, and the content header. Thanks a lot